# Why don't Spring actuator requests display in log?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have 6 Springboot apps. Each one is slightly different from another. All of them include Actuator (so I can hit /health, /env, etc). The problem is that in 3 of the apps I can see in the logs where the request was processed for each endpoint (see example below). In the other 3 apps I do not get this log info. I have tried to copy some config code and dependencies from one app to the other but have not figured out what is different or how to change the logging configuration. Has anyone discovered how to solve this problem?

```
2016-12-15 20:02:04.962 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/health]
```